# Extjs 4.1, Making JSON array for Store sync

Tags: extjs4.1

When I sync for edited grid, extjs pass JSON data to Server by AJAX.

If I edit multiple row, and sync then it make JSON array. But if I edit just single row,
it will pass just a JSON data.

So I have some problem with receiving the parameter because the parameter type is vary.

My question is,

Is it possible to make **JSON array** date even for single edited grid?

If so, how should I do? anybody know please please advice me.

**[Single]**

[image]

**[Multiple]**

[image]

And this is part of grid store,

```
proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        api: {
            update: 'Order/ItemUpdate',
            read: 'Order/ItemList',
            create: undefined,
            destroy: undefined
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the `allowSingle` config of `Ext.data.writer.Json` to **false**. As covered [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle) in the docs.

I am pretty sure that this can be done from your proxy config, e.g.:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        allowSingle: false
    },
    api: {
        update: 'Order/ItemUpdate',
        read: 'Order/ItemList',
        create: undefined,
        destroy: undefined
    }
}
```